# Persist existing entities more than once (duplicate key) for @OneToMany entity

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have an entity `Pack` that should contain a `List` of `MenuItem` entity objects, and each `MenuItem` object should be persistable to more than one `Pack`.

**Edit**

I used `@ManyToMany` annotation in the `Pack` entity:

```
   public class Pack {
   ...

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "packs")
    private List<MenuItem> menuItems;
  }
```

And in the `MenuItem` entity:

```
public class MenuItem{
 ...

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "pack_menu_items",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "menu_item_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "pack_id") }
)
private List<Pack> packs;
}
```

This way, a table with the name `pack_menu_items` is generated in Postgres database.

Now I have tried to create a new `Pack` object and affecting it a `MenuItem` List at the same time but that didn't work:
[post request: Pack with menuItems (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM95e.png)

And I have tried to add `menuItems` to a `Pack` separately:

```
@Override
public Pack addItems(int id, List<MenuItem> menuItems) {
    Pack pack = get(id);
    assert pack != null;
    List<MenuItem> menuItemsWillUpdate = pack.getMenuItems();
    menuItemsWillUpdate.addAll(menuItems);
    pack.setMenuItems(menuItemsWillUpdate);
    return repository.save(pack);
}
```

And yet no luck in getting rows inserted in the new Table `pack_menu_items`;

Any help with that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `Pack` can contain multiple `MenuItem`s and a `MenuItem` can belong to multiple `Pack`s this is in fact not a `OneToMany` but a `ManyToMany`-relationship.

There's a different annotation for those, `@ManyToMany`. To learn more about this, I'd suggest following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many) tutorial on the topic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have a question, The mentioned tutorial works with `HashSet` object instead of `List` object, and I have seen it a lot previously @ManyToMany, is that relevant or has a meaning?

Comment: I wasn't aware of a specific reason (I tend to avoid using ManyToMany and use a dedicated junction entity which I manage myself for clarity) but after some searching I learned that apparently using a Set instead of a List allows Hibernate to optimize delete-statements much more (as can be seen in [this](https://dzone.com/articles/why-set-is-better-than-list-in-manytomany) blogpost).

Comment: Well I used  `List` and I had the deleting problem, so I had to do it manually. Thank you for your help.